# I can't play my best/full in a football match in the morning

Tags: football, sports-psychology

My club play almost all of its matches in the morning, but in this time my body still feels kinda relaxed and I'm not mentally motivated or physically. Plus I can't sprint or accelerate as fast. When we play in the afternoon, it's a completely different story, where I run at defenders and they scream.

Could someone please help me to know what I can do in the morning to wake up and motivate myself?

Comment: Do you stretch/prepare in the morning? By the afternoon, one tends to be more awake/prepared, like you, but this is different per person.

Comment: Well, we stretch and practice, and warm up for half an hour before the match like usual, but I neither have that physical sharpness nor the mental motivation to destroy the game. Btw thank you for responding

Comment: Okay. I'm not a morning person either so I empathize with you. I tend to play better (not necessarily football, but the sports I do play) as the game goes on. Nonetheless, good question.

Comment: Are you a rapidly-accelerating attacker needing explosive speed? Or are you a more muscular midfielder accelerating slowly? In which level are you playing? Are you playing Vo2Max level every game so you hit a threshold (containing lactic acid etc) after a time after which you can push far harder? Do you enjoy proper recovery meal after every training? Do you feel muscle soreness or lack of energy or both on the morning?

Comment: This might be a bit simplistic but you could always try and get up earlier on the day of a match so you have a bit longer to prepare yourself mentally and physically. Personally I always used smelling salts to get me going for an early morning match!

Comment: Some very nice feedback, thank you! Well, I wake up ver early, 5:30 am, haha. The smelling salts is a good idea so I might try that.

Comment: To answer hhh, I am more of an explosive player that accelerates fast. I don't really have much of a recovery meal, I play to my max, I am playing at youth level (I am 15). In the morning I can sorta feel that my legs are less swift, sharp, powerful. But in the afternoon it's different.

Comment: @user3609242 how old are you?

Answer (score 4):

I used to have the same problem doing another sport, swimming. I used to have competitions and trainings in the morning all the time, and for sports, it is not unusual.

The best routine to get yourself used to, as far as I'm concerned and what I learned through my 12 years of swimming:

1. Obviously, try to sleep early. You need to get at least 8 hours of sleep before a big game. In addition, it's always best to sleep extra early to plan to wake up at least 1-1.5 hours before you leave your house for the game. The human body is in a fragile state when you wake up in the morning, and the more time that passes by, the more that your body gets used to the environment around it.
2. Also very important, have a big breakfast meal. As you may know, breakfast is the most important meal of the day. Make sure to have a big breakfast that will give you energy for your game. Try to have with you at all time in addition a power bar that you can take about 30-45 minutes before the game. Drink lots and lots of water.
3. Finally, make sure you warm up correctly, and stretch before the game. As I said, your body is very fragile in the morning and since you'd been asleep for 8 hours or so, your body can't stand it if you make sudden movements all of a sudden after being idle for so long. So it's important to gradually prepare your body for the game through warming up and stretching, rather than warming up very fast 10 minutes before your game.